# Java Error Erroneous sym type: setDefaultCloseOperation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm quite new to Java especially when it comes to building JFrames. I've been getting the above error and the problem seems to come from the Generated Code.
Please assist me in clearing the error and understanding what causes it.

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class CalcForm {

    /**
     * Creates new form CalcForm
     */
    public CalcForm() {
        initComponents();
   }



     //The Auto-Generated Code begins here
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        input1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        input2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLess = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnEquals = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        disp = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        //The two lines below are highlighted in RED
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Simple Calcucator");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("First Input:");

        input1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                input1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Second Input:");

        input2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                input2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnAdd.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.setText("+");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnLess.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        btnLess.setText("-");
        btnLess.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLessActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnEquals.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        btnEquals.setText("=");
        btnEquals.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnEqualsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Your Answer is:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(btnEquals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 123, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 137, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(input1)
                            .addComponent(btnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(116, 116, 116)
                                .addComponent(btnLess, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(input2)
                            .addComponent(disp))))
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(input1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnLess, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(input2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnEquals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(disp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
       //This also has a Red underline
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>



    private void input1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void input2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    }                                      

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

        btnAdd.setActionCommand("+");


    }                                      

    private void btnLessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

        btnLess.setActionCommand("-");

    }                                       

    private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        btnEquals.setActionCommand("=");
        String less = btnLess.getActionCommand();
        String more = btnAdd.getActionCommand();
        double t = 0;
        String x = input2.getText();
        //parseDouble is a method used to read the given object as a double value
        double y = Double.parseDouble(x);

        String a = input1.getText();
        double b = Double.parseDouble(a);
        if (less.equals(evt)) {

            t = b - y;
            disp.setText(String.valueOf(t));

        } else {

            t = b + y;
            disp.setText(String.valueOf(t));

        }

    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {



        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CalcForm();



            }
        });

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEquals;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLess;
    private javax.swing.JTextField disp;
    private javax.swing.JTextField input1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField input2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

The errors displayed are:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: setDefaultCloseOperation
    at calculator.CalcForm.initComponents(CalcForm.java:43)
    at calculator.CalcForm.<init>(CalcForm.java:21)
    at calculator.CalcForm$6.run(CalcForm.java:232)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Highly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try running your app if there are still compilation errors listed in the *Problems* view of Eclipse.

Your class dosn't extend JFrame, so it doesn't have any `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method. It also doesn't have any `setTitle()`, `add()` `pack()`, etc. method. You missed the `extends JFrame` part in the class declaration.